# What in the BOTW game engine makes physics behave wildly when certain actions are triggered during bullet-time?

Tags: physics, physics-engine

What in the BOTW game engine makes physics behave wildly when certain actions are triggered during bullet-time?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXKsTrwZ6XY

Also, what can you do to prevent it? Is this problem unavoidable when you include bullet-time?

Comment: Probably it is better to word this question in terms of imitating that behavior. Yes, it can be avoided. It seems to be something with time scaling. I'm not sure if forces, velocities, or what.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't know exactly what's going wrong. There are a few possibilities, but absent a dev coming here and telling us, this question can't be answered.

Comment: Is this a problem you've encountered in your own game? Showing us how you've run into it in your own development can make it easier to find fixes/preventative measures that will work for your context.